# imshow assertion failed drawChessboardCorner() of opencv returns nothing in Python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am new in OpenCV programming in Python. Tried with most basic camera feed program that went well. When trying to calibrate a pinhole camera using [OpenCV Calibration and 3d Reconstruction](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html#calibration) tutorial I am getting assertion error at `imshow()` function after `drawChessboardCorners()`.
I used a lots of print command for debugging purpose and saw it found corners successfully, shows type of image after reading from file is `numpy.ndarray` which is vast confusing to me.

How it is possible that `imread()` returns `numpy.ndarray`?

Please help.

My opencv version is 2.4.6 and python version is 2.7 on windows8 64 bit.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

#termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

#prepare object points, like (0,0,0,), (1,0,0), (2,0,0)......, (6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7, 0:6].T.reshape(-1, 2)

#Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] #3d points in real world
imgpoints = [] #2d points in image plane

images = glob.glob('images\*.jpg')
#print images
print ' '*8
for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    #size = (int(img.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(img.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
    print ' '
    print ' '
    print 'Type of image after reading', type(img)
    #print img.ndim
    #print img.size.width
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    print 'Processing', fname

    #find chessboard corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (7, 6), None)
    #print 'Corners', corners
    #print ret

    #If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        print 'Corners found in', fname
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray, corners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
        print 'Corners2', corners2
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        #Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7, 6), corners2, ret)
        print 'Type of img after drawChessboardCorners', type(img)
        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)
    else:
        print 'Corners not found in', fname
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output:

```
Type of image after reading <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
Processing images\left01.jpg
Corners found in images\left01.jpg
Corners2 None
Type of image after drawChessboardCorners <type 'NoneType'>
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp, line 261
Traceback (most recent call last):
File: "PythonCameraCalibration.py", Line 47, in<module>
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\src\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:261: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0
```

Comment: Please post your code and the stack trace of the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem is that you are assigning the output of

```
cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7, 6), corners2, ret)
```

to img, which the tutorial does not do. This function call is probably not returning anything. Try removing the assignment from that line and see what happens.

Comment: Great!! How childish act of mine.

Comment: It works fine. I could not think how I overlooked this.. Shame

Comment: Yes!! Certainly. Why not?

Comment: I mean my answer. The check button next to up/down arrows.